# get the words and the characters between the words of a text

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text, for example

```
my $text = "share your knowledge, Q&A-style"
```

and would like to get the words *and* the characters between them in a list. If I use

```
my (@parts) = $text =~ /(\w+)/g
```

I get

```
("share", "your", "knowledge", "Q", "A", "style")
```

Now I'd like to get the following list:

```
("share", "your", "knowledge", ",", "Q", "&", "A", "-", "style")
```

Is there a way to do this beside looping over the text character by character?

Comment: You probably want to use a split method instead of regex and tell it to split on word boundaries `\b` [example](https://regex101.com/r/ewu7xc/1) I dont know perl so I cant say exactly how to implement that

Comment: The really used regular expression is more complex than in the example above, it's something like "[abcABC]{3,}".

Comment: In the expected list, is the space after the comma really wanted or is it a typo?

Comment: It's a typo, I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

By using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and putting the regex in parenthesis, it will return the separators also. Then remove empty parts (containing only space) by using `grep`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "share your knowledge, Q&A-style";
my @parts =  grep { /\S/ } split /(\w+)/, $text;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple if you write a regular expression that will match *either* a sequence of "word" characters *or* a sequence of non-word non-space characters

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $text = "share your knowledge, Q&A-style";

my @parts = $text =~ /\w+|[^\w\s]+/g;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

print Dumper \@parts;
```

#### output

```
[
  "share",
  "your",
  "knowledge",
  ",",
  "Q",
  "&",
  "A",
  "-",
  "style"
]
```

The only discrepancy is that your example output shows an element `", "` (with a space) after *knowledge*. I'm guessing that's a mistake as all other spaces are discarded, but if you really want to capture any spaces that follow non-word sequences then you just need to change the regex pattern to `$text =~ /\w+|[^\w\s]+\s*/g`

Answer (score -1):

To get the matches you want you should use regex like this `\b(?:\S|\S+?\s+?)+?\b` [example](https://regex101.com/r/i55G0R/2)

It will match any non whitespace character set Or a non whitespace character followed by whitespace (to account for your ", " condition).

I think you may also want to look into a `split` function on word endings and eliminate empty (only whitespace) matches.